# Voting bug....?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

An hour ago I downvoted a reply, but within a minute canceled the downvote.  That succeeded: the vote count returned to its original value and, even now, there is no indication on the page that I ever voted.  Now I wish to upvote that reply, but am told that "You last voted on this answer / 1 hour ago / Your vote is now locked in..."  This looks like a bug.  Has anyone else experienced it?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps there could be a mechanism to forward a request to MODS.  What if someone inadvertently downvoted when they meant to upvote (or vica versa)?  They would lose the ability to reflect their true preference.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent weird vote-gaming shenanigans, you can only change your vote a limited number of times. And once you vote *at all*, the clock starts ticking on the lock, regardless of the state of the vote.

Comment: Does that mean you can only change your vote on a particular post a limited number of times?  Or can you only change your vote on all posts a limited number of times?  How many times?  I tried to change a vote on something that I voted on 17 hours ago.  Surely, that's enough time to change my mind.